# How to use dynamic variables defined in chef recipe to replace the expression in template file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am stuck with a situation where I have created a templates/test.sh.erb file with below content:

```html
#!/bin/bash

ls -ltr <%= "#{tomcat_home}/instance1/bin" %>
ls -ltr <%= "#{tomcat_home}/instance1/conf" %>
```

For this erb file, I wanted to pass "tomcat_home" which can be either "/opt/tomcat" or "/opt/apacheTomcat". This data I am parsing using if else condition which is returning me tomcat home either one of this path.

```
eg: tomcat_home="/opt/tomcat"
```

I wanted to create the test.sh file at /tmp location on server in which I wanted to replace the tomcat_home variable dynamically whenever it will create the test.sh file .
template resource logic:

```html
    template "/tmp/test.sh" do
        source 'test.sh.erb' # <-- this is your directory in files/default/local_directory
        owner 'tomcat'                                                                 
        group 'tomcat'
        mode '0755'
        action :create                                                                   
    end
```

Desired output I am expecting when template resource will run:

```html
#!/bin/bash

ls -ltr /opt/tomcat/instance1/bin
ls -ltr /opt/tomcat/instance1/conf
```

Answer (score 2):

For variable interpolation in [Chef templates](https://docs.chef.io/resources/template/) (`.erb` files), `<%= %>` markers should be used. In your case, only the `tomcat_home` variable should be inside these markers, i.e. `<%= tomcat_home %>`.

Also, the files that need templating, should be under the `<cookbook_name>/templates/default` directory. The `files/` directory is for static files, where variable interpolation *does not happen*.

Example:

`templates/default/test.sh.erb`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ls -ltr <%= @tomcat_home %>/instance1/bin
ls -ltr <%= @tomcat_home %>/instance1/conf
```

Then in recipe:

```rb
template '/tmp/test.sh' do
  source 'test.sh.erb'
  owner 'tomcat'                                                                 
  group 'tomcat'
  mode '0755'
  variables(
    tomcat_home: '/opt/tomcat'
  )
end
```

Note that the `:create` action is default for the `template` resource, so I omitted it. Also, the templates can refer to node attributes directly, like:

```
ls -ltr <%= node['cookbook_name']['tomcat_home'] %>/instance1/bin
```

Comment: Thanks Seshadri. It worked. I have another issue where I am running a shell script and when I trigger it manually I am getting exit code as 4 but when I am triggering it with bash resorce its executing script but throwing error as ">>>> Caused by Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '4'" . Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: As the command is exiting with non-zero code, it is considered as failed command. Do you mind creating a new question with the required details?